# C: Array output

Tags: c, arrays

Given an integer array, I'm trying to print the array with all the zeros moved to the left of the array. The order of the remaining numbers doesn't matter. I keep getting strange outputs like "{-1073741824,1049472,1,49,63,1055984,1}" for the array that is hardcoded in main.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a[10] = {3, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 7, 20, 1, 5};
    int n = 10;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] == 0)
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    //////////

    int *array = malloc(0);
    for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
    {
        array = realloc(array, (j + 1) * sizeof(int));
        array[j] = 0;
    }

    //////////

    printf("%s", "{");
    for (int k = 0; k < n-1; ++k)
    {
        if (array[k] != 0)
        {
            printf("%d%s", array[k], ",");
        }
    }
    printf("%d", array[n-1]);
    printf("%s", "}\n");

    //////////

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, you define a as an array. Then you define another array, named array. Then you use array. But where do you use or copy the values from a?

Comment: Why not use a simple sort algorithm?

Comment: `malloc(0)` is undefined behavior... Though you've certainly used it in an interesting way. :)  I doubt it's the source of your problem.  Take note that you may actually have a valid pointer returned from that of a minimum allocation size (8 or 16 bytes).  It's also a super good idea to check that malloc and realloc return valid pointers any time they are called.

Comment: Thanks AndASM, I realized that I'm printing from the wrong array. I'll see if I can fix it!

Comment: I suggest you learn some basic debugging skills either with a source level debugger or with well-placed `printf()` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace:

```
int *array = malloc(0);
for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
{
    array = realloc(array, (j + 1) * sizeof(int));
    array[j] = 0;
}
```

With something like:

```
int array[10]; //malloc(0);
int j = 0;
for (j = 0; j < count; ++j)
{
    array[j] = 0;
}

for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
{
    if(a[j]!=0)
        array[count++] = a[j];
}
```

If you use this code you don't need `malloc`, `realloc` neither `free`.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks overly complicated - you don't need to pass a string in using %s you can just print it directly.  So

```
printf("%s", "{");
```

can be:

```
print("{");
```

After your first step, you could just print the number of zeros you've found, followed by stepping through and printing all the non-zero integers.  Something a bit like this

```
int a[10] = {3, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 7, 20, 1, 5};
int n = 10;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (a[i] == 0)
    {
        ++count;
    }
}
printf("{");
for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
{
     printf("0,");
}
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
     if (a[i]!=0) {
         printf("%d", a[i]);
         if (i < n-1) {
             printf(",");
         }
     }
}
printf("}\n");
```